# Simple Probability Distribution Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Alice flips a fair coin n times and Bob flips another fair coin n + 1 times, resulting in independent X $\sim$ Bin(n, 1/2) and Y $\sim$ Bin(n + 1, 1/2).

Can someone please explain to me, in simple english, why this statement is true?

$$P(X<Y)=P(n−X<n+1−Y)$$

The random variable Y is not inherently larger than X, so why is that statement true?

Comment: Use `$\sim$` for $\sim$.

Comment: It I tell you that (i) $X$ and $n-X$ are identically distributed; and (ii) that $Y$ and $(n+1)-Y$ are identically distributed; can you see why it's true?

Comment: I think so. Would this statement also be true for P(n*X < (n+1)*Y)?

Comment: @Workhorse No, not with this sort of transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not specify, I will assume that $X$ and $Y$ count the number of *tails* for Alice and Bob.

- $X<Y$ means that Alice has less *tails* than Bob
- $n-X$ is the Alice's number of *heads* (# of trials - # of tails)
- $n+1-Y$ is Bob's number of *heads* (# of trials - # of tails)

therefore

- $n-X < n+1-Y$ means that Alice has less heads than Bob.

Now, if the coin is fair, counting *heads* leads to the same probability as counting *tails* (this is symmetry); therefore
$$
P(X<Y)=P(n-X < n+1-Y).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Binomial coefficients [have a symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula) that can be written

$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$$

$Y$ is a random variable following a binomial distribution with parameters $n+1$ and $1/2$. When the second parameter is $1/2$, the symmetry in binomial coefficients extends to a symmetry in the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function):

\begin{align}
P(Y=k) &= \binom{n+1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1-k} \\
&= \binom{n+1}{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\\\\
P(Y=n+1-k) &= \binom{n+1}{n+1- k }\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1-k} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1 - (n+1-k)}\\
 &=\binom{n+1}{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\\\\
\end{align}

We have, for all $k$, the symmetric relationship

$$P(Y=k) = P(Y = n + 1 - k) = \binom{n+1}{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}$$

Similarly, $X$ has parameters $n$ and $1/2$, so we have, for all $h$,

$$P(X = h) = P(X = n - h) =\binom{n}{h} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}$$