# $X \sim Bin(n,1/2), n-X \sim Bin(n,1/2)$

Tags: probability

Alice flips a fair coin $n$ times and Bob flips another fair coin $n+ 1$ times, resulting
in independent $X \sim Bin(n,1/2)$ and $Y \sim Bin(n+1,1/2)$. Is it true that $P(X < Y) = P(n-X < n+1-Y)$

I said the answer is no because if $X,Y$ count the number of tails, then $n-x,n+1-Y$ count the number of heads.

So, $P(X < Y) \neq P(n-X < n+1-Y)$ because if $n =8$ and $X=5,Y=8$, then $P(5<8) \neq P(3 < 1)$

But, as seen here ([Simple Probability Distribution Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461596/simple-probability-distribution-question)) this is wrong.

Comment: But $P(X<Y, X=5,Y=8) = P(8-X<8+1-Y, 8-X=5, 8+1-Y=8)$  ... or more clearly if you let $W$ and $Z$ be the relevant counts for heads ($W=8-X$, $Z=9-Y$). $$P(X<Y, X=5,Y=8) =P(W<Z, W=5,Z=8) $$  And by Total Probability: $$\begin{align} \mathsf P(X<Y)&=\sum_{i=0}^8\sum_{j=i}^9 \mathsf P(X=i,Y=j)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^8\sum_{j=i}^9 \mathsf P(W=i,Z=j)\\&=\mathsf P(W<Z)\end{align}$$

Comment: (Which of course only holds when we have the symmetry of head and tail distributions from tossing fair coins.)

Comment: You are mixing up equality of probabilities with equality of events.  In particular, by the time you've written $P(5<8) \neq P(3 < 1)$, you've already made this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$, $Y$ and $n$ are all integers, you have the event equivalence:

$$\begin{align}
X < Y 
&\quad \iff \quad n+X < n+Y \\[6pt]
&\quad \iff \quad n-Y < n - X \\[6pt]
&\quad \iff \quad n+1-Y \leqslant  n - X \\[6pt]
&\quad \iff \quad \neg (n-X < n+1-Y), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

so you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(X < Y) = 1- \mathbb{P}(n-X < n-Y+1).$$

If you combine this result with your conjectured equation you get:

$$\mathbb{P}(n-X < n-Y+1) = \mathbb{P}(X < Y) = 1- \mathbb{P}(n-X < n-Y+1),$$

which would imply that:

$$\mathbb{P}(X < Y) = \mathbb{P}(n-X < n-Y+1) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

So, it remains to check if this equation holds.

Answer (score 1):

> So, $P(X < Y) \neq P(n-X < n+1-Y)$ because if $n =8$ and $X=5,Y=8$, then $P(5<8) \neq P(3 < 1)$

To the point, you're mixing up equality of **probabilities of events** with equality of the **events** themselves.  That is, while $A=B$ always implies $P(A) = P(B)$, we may have $A\neq B$ while still having $P(A)=P(B)$.  This isn't a contradiction, so showing $A\neq B$ **does not** show us $P(A) \neq P(B)$.

In your case, you have two events:

- $X < Y$
- $n-X < n+1-Y$

These are not the same events (in fact, they're complementary).  That is, setting $n,X,Y$ may make one event occur while the other doesn't occur, but importantly, this doesn't impact whether these two events are equally likely.  While we can consider a particular value of the parameter $n$, once we choose particular values of $X$ or $Y$, we're no longer talking about probabilities; we're talking about events.